# Update into database fail

Tags: php, mysql

i tried to update my database but its not working.i did the var_dump and it seems my $_post is working.

here is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Update')
{   
var_dump($_POST);

mysqli_query($link," UPDATE storage_details
              SET   status='".$_POST['status']."',
              itemCODE='".$_POST['itemCODE']."',
              WHERE ID='".$_POST['ID']."';");

}
```

this is my form where i do the post method to update my database

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="form-group"> 
<label>Enter Items ID</label>
<input id="ID" name="ID" class="form-control">
<p class="help-block">Make Sure the ID is correct.</p>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Approval</label>
<select id="status" name="status" class="form-control">
<option value="Approved">Approved</option>
<option value="Not Approved">Not Approved</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>item CODE</label>
<input id="itemCODE" name="itemCODE" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>

<input class="btn btn-default pad" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

i tried to run this query into my database

```
UPDATE storage_details SET
            status='approved',
            itemCODE='123',
            WHERE ID='2';
```

apparently i got this error 
     #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID='2'' at line 4

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: no error.it just did not update into the database?

Comment: You should be using bind parameters!

Comment: i edited my code so try it now

Comment: there shouldn't be a trailing comma here `itemCODE='" . $_POST['itemCODE'] . "',` <<< and using error checking http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  would have told you about the syntax error.

Comment: `itemCODE='123',` <<< same thing but nobody is listening. I am now moving on. Good luck.

Comment: hey i added it to my post @Fred -ii-

Comment: I hope the OP never goes LIVE with this @JackSmith  they're open to a serious SQL injection. and the W.W.W.(o.)H. loves to hack people's databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE storage_details SET
                status='" . $_POST['status'] . "',
                itemCODE='" . $_POST['itemCODE'] . "'
                WHERE id=" . $_POST['ID'] . "");
```

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in D:\xampp\htdocs\testsubject\Admin\pages\tables.php on line 25

Comment: can you tell me the name of you database connection?

Comment: Here `$link` is the database connection. Besides, `mysqli_query()` doesn't take three parameters.

Comment: did you try it? @Ashraf Kamarudin

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\testsubject\Admin\pages\tables.php on line 24` this is what i get..

Comment: try it now @Ashraf Kamarudin

Comment: there shouldn't be a trailing comma here `itemCODE='" . $_POST['itemCODE'] . "',` <<<

Comment: ok try one more time see if it works and say thank you to fred if it works please

Comment: dude ! that one works ! thank you fred ! and u too @jack smith.thank you for trying so hard to help me.

Comment: lucky I posted that huh? otherwise, you'd be at the same spot.

Comment: we probably be at the same spot for a few mins Fred but thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a small syntax error in your query. Here's the fix:

```
mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE storage_details
                    SET status='".$_POST['status']."',
                    itemCODE='".$_POST['itemCODE']."'
                    WHERE ID='".$_POST['ID']."'");
```

Comment: there shouldn't be a trailing comma here `itemCODE='" . $_POST['itemCODE'] . "',` <<<